# Postfix evaluator not returning correct results

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I've been trying to figure out my code's bugs to no avail. I'm supposed to code an infix to postfix translator, in addition to evaluating the postfix expression. My code runs, but unfortunately it doesn't return the correct value.

I have a calculator GUI that calls the code shown below whenever the equals sign is pressed. The calculator passes as an argument a string separated by spaces. I then use the String Tokenizer on this space separated string and work from there. I can provide the code for the calculator GUI if it helps.

My problem lies with the answer the calculator provides. For example, if I input (5+2), the calculator returns 2 as an answer, and if I press the equals sign again it returns 5 as an answer. If I input (5*2)+(3*9), it returns 9 as an answer, and if I press the equals sign again it returns 5 as an asnwer. I've tried going through my code multiple times but unfortunately I haven't been able to find my mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

DISCLAIMER: I am aware of the side note regarding the use of String Tokenizer. I would use something else but that is one of requirements. I haven't implemented any error checking yet or the checking of precedence because I want to make sure it works correctly assuming the input is correct and isn't excessively complicated first. Also, I'm aware that my code won't correctly process something like (5+2)-1 because of the lack of parenthesis around the 1. But then again it won't work with something even simpler than that so...I'll worry about that once I can get it to work with simpler input. Finally, this is indeed a homework assignment, but please don't think I want this to be done for me completely. Just a few pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class ExpressionEvaluator {

Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();
Queue<String> myQueue = new Queue<>();

String curToken; //Current token of my tokenized string.
double temp1;    //Place holder for first value of the calc section.
double temp2;    //Place holder for second value of the calc section.

public String processInput(String s) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

        curToken = st.nextToken();

        if (openParenthesis(curToken)) {
            myStack.push(curToken);
        }

        if (closeParenthesis(curToken)) {
            do {
                myQueue.enqueue(myStack.pop());
            } while (!openParenthesis(myStack.peek()));
        }

        if (isOperator(curToken)) {
            while (!myStack.isEmpty() && !openParenthesis(myStack.peek())) {
                myQueue.enqueue(myStack.pop());
            }
            myStack.push(curToken);
        }
        if (isDouble(curToken)) {
            myQueue.enqueue(curToken);
        }
    }

    while (!myStack.isEmpty()) {
        myQueue.enqueue(myStack.pop());
    }

    while (!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
        if (isDouble(myQueue.peek())) {
            myStack.push(myQueue.dequeue());
        }

        else if (isOperator(myQueue.peek())) {
            temp1 = Double.parseDouble(myStack.pop());
            temp2 = Double.parseDouble(myStack.pop());
            myStack.push(Double.toString(calc(temp1, temp2)));
        }

        else {
            myQueue.dequeue();
        }
    }
    return myStack.pop();
}

 //Private methods used to simplify/clarify some things.


 //Checks if input is an operator, returns true if it is
private boolean isOperator(String str) {
    if (str == "+") {return true;}
    else if (str == "-") {return true;}
    else if (str == "*") {return true;}
    else if (str == "/") {return true;}
    else if (str == "^") {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

 //Checks if input is an open parenthesis "(", returns true if it is

private boolean openParenthesis(String str) {
    if (str == "(") {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

 //Checks if input is a close parenthesis ")", returns true if it is

private boolean closeParenthesis(String str) {
    if (str == ")") {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

 //Checks if input is a double, returns true if it is
 //I actually got this method from Stack Overflow, so thanks!

private boolean isDouble(String str) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

 //Method used to actually do the calculations. I have
 //a feeling this is where my problem is, but I can't
 //think of a way to fix it.

private double calc(double a, double b) {
    String op = myQueue.dequeue();

    if (op == "+") {return a+b;}
    else if (op == "-") {return a-b;}
    else if (op == "*") {return a*b;}
    else if (op == "/") {return a/b;}
    else if (op == "^") {return Math.pow(a, b);}
    else {throw new UnknownElementException(null, "ERROR");}
}
 }
```

Sorry for the weird indentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm named *Shunting-yard* which specifies how to convert infix notation to post fix notation (also referred to as "Reverse Polish Notation"). Then you won't have to worry about operator precedence.

It uses a queue and a stack. Basically when you encounter a digit you add it to the queue. And when you encounter operators you push them on to the stack.

You can find the detailed algorithm here : [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Once in reverse polish notation you can easily evaluate it like described here : 
[Postfix evaluation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! I was using == instead of .equals() to compare the strings in my isOperator, closeParenthesis, and openParenthesis methods.